# Правильное оформление поля

Tags: c#, классы, оформление

Есть поле состоящее из клеток, а точнее объектов класса `Cell`.
Как лучше и правильнее в этом классе прописать тип поля?
`string Type;` который может быть равен например "Земля" или "Вода" это я так понимаю не очень правильно.
Это лучше делать через перечисления? Или int который может быть равен например 1 или 2, а в комментарии сказать, что одно это земля, а другое вода. Но я понимаю так тоже не красиво.
Если можно примеры.

Comment: Используйте перечисление.

Comment: Смотря какая реакция ожидается от клеток. Можно сделать в духе ООП: каждая клетка - класс. Наследование, полиморфизм, все дела... Можно наворотить тонны кода на ровном месте (если вам платят за количество строк). PS: но перечисления явно проще (на первом этапе)

Comment: Мне нужно в духе ООП, и желательно пример

Comment: Уточните: под полем подразумевается игровое поле?

Comment: Да, есть генератор, который делает поле либо Землёй, либо Водой  
```public class Cell {
public enum TypeCell { Water, Earth }
public TypeCell Type { get; set; } }```
Пока что сделал так, но не уверен что это в духе ООП

Comment: Есть несколько вариантов. Можно конечно сделать Enum и все дела. Как альтернатива, можно определить интерфейс для ячейки и написать разные реализации для земли/воды/чего угодно. Тут уже вам решать, как лучше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас не правильная модель. Вы не должны хранить клетки как отдельный класс, а как структуру.

```cs
public class Field
{
    Cell[] cells;

    public ref Cell this[int index] => ref cells[index]; // можно добавить кастомный чек на индекс
}
```

```cs
public struct Cell
{
    public CellType CellType { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public enum CellType
{
    Empty, // или Unknow, или Invalid // лучше определять пустую вариацию поля
    Earth,
    Water,
    ⋮
}
```

Такая модель обеспечит вам минимальную нагрузку на кучу, при этом вы копируете именно ссылку, а не всю структуру.

---

Касаемо вопроса об том, где хранить тип клетки: тут всё зависит от вашей программы. Если типы клетки *статичны*, т. е. известны заранее, то самым лучшим решением окажется `enum` – минимальная нагрузка на память без потери читабельности (использовать вместо `enum` `int` – это худшее, что вы можете сделать). *Но*, если захотите определять типы *динамически*, т. е. во время run-time'а (запуска программы), то тут лучше использовать наследование (в случае с абстрактным классом: давайте не забывать, что интерфейсы мы *не наследуем*, а *реализуем*) и сделать что-то типо этого:

```
public interface ICellType
{
    // какие-то св-ва вашего типа, по типу: проходимость, текстура и т. д.
}
```